# chrome.storage.sync does not store the data

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to store the data a user enters inside a textarea in a `popup.html`. Using jQuery on `window unload` the data should be synced and on `window ready` the data should be restored. However, when opening `popup.html` the content of the textarea is `undefined`. This is the jQuery code which I am loading in `popup.html`:

```
$(window).unload (
    function save() {
        var textarea = document.querySelector("#contacts").value;
        // Old method of storing data locally
        //localStorage["contacts"] = textarea.value;

        // Save data using the Chrome extension storage API.
        chrome.storage.sync.set({contacts: textarea}, function() {
            console.log("Contacts saved");
        });
    });

$(window).ready(
    function restore() {
        var textarea = document.querySelector("#contacts");
        // Old method of retrieving data locally
        // var content = localStorage["contacts"];
        chrome.storage.sync.get('contacts', function(r) {
            console.log("Contacts retrieved");
            var content = r["contacts"];
            textarea.value = content;
        });
    });
```

Comment: It seems that once `unload` has fired, it is too late to successfully perform a `sync.set` operation. Have you considered incrementally storing the data, or experimenting with `onbeforeunload`? (I'm not sure `onbeforeunload` will work either, though.)

Comment: Using `$(window).onbeforeunload()` raises `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onbeforeunload'`.

Comment: Aside from the technical problem of using the unload event for saving data, you probably don't want to risk the user's data waiting for that part of the page lifetime anyway. The browser might crash, the user might experience a power failure, who knows. Better to design for a save right after the data's creation/alteration.

Answer (score 4):

From popup.js you can invoke a method in background.js file to save the data:

**popup.js:**

```
addEventListener("unload", function(){
    var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    background.mySavefunction(data);
}
```

**background.js**:

```
function mySaveFunction(data){
    chrome.storage.sync.set(data, function(){
       console.log("Data saved.");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Instead of using `$(window).unload()` I now use a submit button which needs to be clicked before closing `popup.html`:

```
$("#save-button").click(function() {
        var textarea = document.querySelector("#contacts").value;
        var save = {};
        save["contacts"] = textarea;
        // Save data using the Chrome extension storage API.
        chrome.storage.sync.set(save, function() {
            console.log("Contacts saved");
        });
        $("#confirm").text("Contacts saved.").show().fadeOut(5000);
});
```